# Ayuda con "Intent" en android

Tags: java, android

al momento de ejecutar la apk y pulsar el botón para realizar el calculo matemático mi aplicación se detiene y no se porque , lo que básicamente necesito es que realice una simple suma y el valor lo muestre en otra activit, al presionar el botón calcular haga el calculo y a la vez me envie a la pantalla de la otra activity.

public void onClick(View v)
    {

```
    if (v.getId()==Button1.getId())
    {

        if (Validar())
      {
          Intent Obj1 = new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
          startActivity(Obj1);

          double Numero1 = Double.parseDouble(EditText1.getText().toString());
          double Numero2= Double.parseDouble(EdiText2.getText().toString());
          Double Suma = Numero1+Numero2;
          String Result = "";
          Result = String.valueOf(Suma);
          TextViewResultado.setText("EL RESULTADO ES =" + Result);
      }
    }

}
```

pd. el método validar solo verifica que los edittext no esten vacio

este seria el error que me sale al ejecutar la apk

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta seria mi segunda actividad

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.vistaseundaria); 
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String total = bundle != null ? bundle.getString("total") : ""; 
TextViewResultado.setText(total); 

}
```

Este el error desplegado en el LogCat:

> --------- beginning of crash 2019-05-02 18:58:11.000 13379-13379/com.example.calculadora2_1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.calculadora2_1, PID: 13379
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.calculadora2_1/com.example.calculadora2_1.MainActivity2}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

Comment: Las causas pueden ser diversas, por favor Matias, este tipo de problemas es necesario agregar el mensaje de error que se muestra en el LogCat cuando se cierra la aplicación, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: recuerda agregar actualizaciones a tu pregunta mediante el "editar", ya agregué la  información a tu pregunta, con el mensaje del LogCat es muy sencillo encontrar el problema, agregué respuesta, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debe a que en tu segunda Activity no se esta obteniendo la referencia del TextView:

Obtenla usando `findViewById()`, el elemento se debe encontrar dentro del layout `vistaseundaria.xml`:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.vistaseundaria); 
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); 
  String total = bundle != null ? bundle.getString("total") : ""; 

 //*Obten la referencia.
 TextView TextViewResultado = findViewById(R.id.<id de TextView en vistaseundaria.xml>);

  TextViewResultado.setText(total); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que haces un intent y lo inicias, luego haces un calculo, pero no te llevas ese valor a tu otra actividad.
:

```
//  startActivity(Obj1);  este metodo inicia te lleva a una nueva pantalla.


 if (v.getId()==Button1.getId())
{

    if (Validar())
  {

      double Numero1 = Double.parseDouble(EditText1.getText().toString());
      double Numero2= Double.parseDouble(EdiText2.getText().toString());
      Double Suma = Numero1+Numero2;
      String Result = "";
      Result = String.valueOf(Suma);
      Intent Obj1 = new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
      Obj1.putExtra("total",Result)
      startActivity(Obj1);
  }
}
```

}

Y en tu otra actividad obtener el dato asi:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

String total = bundle != null ? bundle.getString("total") : "";
TextViewResultado.setText(total)
```

Comment: Copie tal cual el código pero al iniciar el apk y ingresar dos valores y darle al botón "calcular" salta un mensaje diciendo "(nombre de la aplicación" se ah detenido")

Comment: @Igmer como sabes que se lleva el valor, en su código no se ve que agregué algo en el Intent.

Comment: @Elenasys porque dice que lo quiere mostrar en otra actividad, tiene que pasarlo en el intent

Comment: Habria que ver si TextViewResultado existe en tu actividad tambien

Comment: Es que son varias las causas, imagina si no tiene definida la Activity destino en su AndroidManifest.xml :( hehe

Comment: @MatiasLuna pero que se muestra en el LogCat como error? :)